# How to get cluster id using kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath, kubectl

I need cluster-id using kubectl command.

```
root@vagrant-xenial64:~# kubectl get cm cluster-info -n kube-system -o jsonpath='{.data.cluster-config\.json}'
{
  "cluster_id": "xxx",
  "cluster_name": "prod-yyy-mmm",
  "cluster_type": "rrr",
  "cluster_pay_tier": "vvv",
  "datacenter": "cse",
  "account_id": "456777",
  "created": "2018-06-32323dffdf:35:48+0000"
}
```

I need `cluster-id` of this particular json

```
root@vagrant-xenial64:~# kubectl get cm cluster-info -n kube-system -o jsonpath='{.data.cluster-config\.json.cluster_id}'
root@vagrant-xenial64:~#
```

Above command returns empty string.
I tried many other combinations too

Comment: Is the [`cluster-info` ConfigMap created by `kubeadm`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/master/docs/design/design_v1.10.md#create-the-public-cluster-info-configmap) or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ConfigMap` resource `data`-field contains a string which are interpreted as-is when you run `jsonpath` to select it via `'{.data.cluster-config\.json}'`. What i mean is that the shell you use will print it as JSON at `stdout` although it's stored differently in Kubernetes. If you run `kubectl get cm cluster-info -n kube-system -o json` and look at the `data`-field it might look something like this:

```
"data": {
    "cluster-config.json": "{\n  \"cluster_id\": \"xxx\",\n  \"cluster_name\": \"prod-yyy-mmm\",\n  \"cluster_type\": \"rrr\",\n  \"cluster_pay_tier\": \"vvv\",\n  \"datacenter\": \"cse\",\n  \"account_id\": \"456777\",\n  \"created\": \"2018-06-32323dffdf:35:48+0000\"\n}\n"
}
```

You won't be able to access the "fields" within that string with `jsonpath` since it's not actually part of the [`ConfigMap` API resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#configmap-v1-core) fields.

You could try to use a second tool to fetch it though, using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a command-line JSON processor. This tool would interpret the output of `jsonpath` as JSON on the fly and parse it accordingly.

Example:

```
kubectl get cm cluster-info -n kube-system -o jsonpath='{.data.cluster-config\.json}' | jq '.cluster_id'
"xxx"
```

If installing e.g. `jq` defeat any purposes i would recommend to use a combination of already available tools (assuming you're on Linux) like `grep`, `awk` and `sed`:

```
kubectl get cm cluster-info -n kube-system -o jsonpath='{.data.cluster-config\.json}' | grep cluster_id | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's/"//' -e 's/",//'
xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

In any pod you can run the following command to get the unique id of that cluster:

`cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt | md5sum`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to obtain a value that uniquely identifies your cluster is [using the `uid` field of the kube-system namespace as a cluster identifier](https://groups.google.com/g/kubernetes-sig-architecture/c/mVGobfD4TpY/m/nkdbkX1iBwAJ):

```
kubectl get ns kube-system -o jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}'
```

Since [kube-system is an immortal namespace](https://groups.google.com/g/kubernetes-sig-architecture/c/mVGobfD4TpY/m/lR4SnaqpAAAJ), it should be safe to assume the `uid` value remains unchanged for throughout a cluster lifetime.

This solution was suggested in the Kubernetes issue on [Unique Id for cluster](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77487).