# How to use kubectl command to get a value from a yaml file inside a k8s configmap?

Tags: kubernetes, jq, jsonpath, go-templates

Assume that the configmap is listed as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
  namespace: ${namespace}
data:
  my-config.yaml: |-
    keyA:
      keyB: a-value
```

How can I get the value of `keyB` (which is `a-value`) from the configmap using the `kubectl` command?

PS: I was thinking of using `-o jsonpath` or `-o 'go-template=...` options, but I couldn't figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: `-o jsonpath` is the way to go. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768988/how-to-save-content-of-a-configmap-to-a-file-with-kubectl-and-jsonpath

I'd provide a full answer, but my `kubectl` is rusty and I don't have a cluster handy. But it looks like @Eduardo's answer below (which I just noticed) covers it.
JSONPath is confusing because it uses those curly braces, unlike `jq`. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `data.my-config.yaml` value either by using `jsonpath` or `go-template`.

Example with `jsonpath`:

```
$ kubectl get cm my-configmap -o "jsonpath={.data['my-config\.yaml']}"
keyA:
  keyB: a-value
```

Example with `go-template`:

```
$ kubectl get cm my-configmap -o 'go-template={{index .data "my-config.yaml"}}'
keyA:
  keyB: a-value
```

Note that by using `|-` on your YAML, you are defining a [Multiline YAML String](https://yaml-multiline.info/), which means that the returned value is a single string with line breaks on it (`\n`).

If you want only the `keyB` value, you can use your output to feed a YAML processor like [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq). E.g:

```
$ kubectl get cm my-configmap -o 'go-template={{index .data "my-config.yaml"}}' | yq -r .keyA.keyB
a-value
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged jq, and since yq is just a wrapper around jq, here's one solution using yq alone:

```
yq -r '.data."my-config.yaml"' configmap.yml |
  yq .keyA.keyB
```

Of course, it might be just as well to use a grep/sed combination along the lines of:

```
 grep keyB: | sed 's/.*keyB: *//'
```

This could be done with the first invocation of yq shown above, or without using yq at all, though of course there are many caveats that go along with such an approach.